# Word AutoOpen for specific File

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to build something like AutoOpen but less generic? So I mean a macro, which executes when you open file xyz.docx.

Comment: Yes, it is. What did you try by your own?

Comment: I just experimented with AutoOpen. Can you tell me how it can be done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open might be helpful

Comment: Please, test the solution I supplied and send some feedback. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Please, copy the next code in "Normal.dotm" "ThisDocument" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Const docName =  "xyz.docx" 'use here the document name you need

Private Sub Document_Open()
   If ActiveDocument.Name = docName Then
       MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name & " has been opened..."
   End If
End Sub
```

The `Open` event is triggered for **any document** being open.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample macro that automatically runs when the document opens. This sample checks whether the user is trying to open a template for editing, then it creates a new document based on the template instead. (Bypass the macro by holding down **Shift** while you open the file).

This sample only makes sense when placed in a macro-enabled template, but you could also add something like this to a macro-enabled document. The document location would also have to be made a trusted location in Windows.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim PathTemp$, NameTemp$
    If ActiveDocument.Type = wdTypeTemplate Then
        NameTemp$ = ActiveDocument.Name
        PathTemp$ = ActiveDocument.Path
        Documents.Add Template:=PathTemp$ & Application.PathSeparator & NameTemp$
        For Each fWindow In Application.Windows
            If fWindow.Caption = NameTemp$ Then
                fWindow.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
            End If
        Next fWindow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When I include your code as an AutoOpen macro and save it as .docm nothing happens. And furthermore I use Word on the Mac.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my post: "This sample only makes sense when placed in a macro-enabled _template_" If you put it in a .docm, it will never be a template and will never do anything. Your original post has no code, and no indication of what problem you're trying to solve, so we have to guess what might work for you.